# Explaining centering a box in a box and resizing window

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to web design and had a question regarding centering and height I was hoping anyone could answer.

I am trying to center a box in a box using CSS. I previously used the CSS code snippet on another page (the part between the "THIS PART" comments, see below) and assumed I would have to put it under the #outer #inner{ part since the inner box is what I want to center. This did not work so I randomly put it in the #outer part and it worked. I'm unsure why and hoped someone could explain to me the reasoning :)

Also, currently I have a background picture and the 2 boxes on my page and when I shrink the page, everything shrinks as well. I assume it is because everything is in percentages. How would I go about making it so when I minimize the screen, everything stays in place and scrollbars appear? I'm having a difficult time finding another question on this site similar.

Please answer whatever you can, any help is appreciated! Thank you so much :)

```css
html{
 height: 97%;
}
body{
 background-image: url("Pic.png");
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
}

#outer{
 border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  height: 99%;
  width: 40%;

  /*THIS PART: START*/
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
  /*THIS PART: END*/

}

#outer #inner{
 position: relative;
  background-color: red;
 
 height: 30%;
 width: 50%;
  
  /*Why doesn't the code from above in #outer go here?*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 <link href = "intro.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div id = "outer">
  <h1>Outer</h1>
  <div id = "inner">
  <h1>Inner</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked because the part

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

affects the inside of the element and not on itself. I am guessing you were expecting the `#outer #inner` to align itself by these lines, but wasn't working.

As for the shrinking problem, I would suggest using pixels or vh/vw instead of percentages

Hope this clears your doubts!

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of it that way :) This makes more sense. Thank you so much for your help and hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

- To start using the **Flexbox model**, you need to first define a
  **flex container.**
- The **flex-wrap** property specifies whether the **flex items**
  should wrap or not.

**Note:** The properties applied to the container are applied to the view of its items.

For reference :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

For the case of **shirinking** problem use px or vh/vw

For reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__KNqdpqji0

Comment: Thank you for the information and reference links! It helped a lot :) Thank you and hope you have a great day!